# How to process PayPal transactions directly through Chase Paymentech Gateway?

Tags: c#, paypal

I have a requirement given to setup shopping cart to accept payments from customers having Paypal accounts. Presently, all the payments are accepted through Credit Cards and Electronic Fund Transfers using Chase Paymentech Gateway.

I did some search on internet and found out that there is a way by which I can accept Paypal payments using Chase paymentech gateway without making much of the changes to my existing system.

But, my problem is that, I cannot find more details on how to do this. The Chase gateway webservice doesn't expose any methods to do this. I have also scanned through the "Chase Paymentech Orbital Gateway SDK" and "Orbital Gateway Interface Specification" documents.

I just have one link which says that it is possible.
https://www.chasepaymentech.com/paypal.html

Also, I know that I have to get this functionality enabled from Chase (for my merchant id) in order to accept payments through Paypal accounts.

All I am looking here is for someone who can guide me on how to do this (accepting payments from paypal accounts using chase gateway) and share any web articles/documents related to it.

Thanks a ton !!

Comment: Did you read the fine print on that page `*PayPal is not available for all customers. Please contact your account manager or a sales representative to find out what options are available for your business.`

Comment: Thanks for replying,

Yes, I have read that, however I am looking for a technical document (guide) on how to consume Chase Paymentech gateway to charge paypal accounts through it.

I am unable to find out anything related to that on internet.

Comment: Well you may want to call your account manager or a sales rep... they might have the information for you. I would start there first.

Comment: Just now I had a call with them and got confirmation that they can enable paypal for my merchant id.

And, they would get a technical team for the support. However, this is going to take time.